# How to display all posts category wise of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a institute website which as courses.
I want to display all posts as list category wise of a custom post type.
for Ex.:

> CATEGORY NAME1
>    - Post of category name 1
>    - Post of category name 1
>   CATEGORY NAME2
>    - Post of category name 2
>    - Post of category name 2

and so on

below is the code which is displaying all posts from custom post type from all categories but i want to show them category wise seperately please help me...

```
<?php
$type = 'course';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1);


$my_query = '';
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to do your query more than once, or one per category the key is adding **'category_name' => 'slug_name'** to your query

```
    <?php
// query category 1   
 $type = 'course';
    $args1=array(
      'post_type' => $type,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'slug_name' // added the category name enter the slug name as defined in the category
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1);

// query category 2   
 $type = 'course';
    $args2=array(
      'post_type' => $type,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'slug_name' // added the category name enter the slug name as defined in the category
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1);

    $my_query = '';
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args1);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();

   $my_query = '';
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args2);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: @X Adams its not working 
and we dont have to add it manually everytime we add a category

Comment: What is the 'slug' name for the category, although you could write a script to  create the code for each slug. thats not the issue now am i correct in thinking you can't query by category_name in your results?

Answer (score 0):

100% working this code

```
$tax_query[] = array(
                 'taxonomy'      => '< taxonomy_slug >',
                'field' => 'term_id', 
                'terms'         => < terms_ids >, // array(12,13,...)

            );

            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => '< post type name>',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'tax_query' => $tax_query
            );

          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            echo  get_the_ID();

          endwhile;
```